# updated my project to angular 9.0 and during build using yarn I get warnings. The projects builds and works fine

Tags: angular, warnings, angular9

I see this on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18 both. Tried reinstalling yarn, reinstalling node and even clearing cache but nothing works, warnings continues. I use script to build and hence the node_module is deleted and installed fresh from package.json locally for the project, for every build done, which has all latest dependencies as of 15-May-2020.

Attaching package.json and warnings below.

**package.json:**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng-load": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.6",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.4.9",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
```

**WARNINGS:**

warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > less > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack > watchpack > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > stylus > css-parse > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > stylus > css-parse > css > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > stylus > css-parse > css > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

warning @angular/cli > universal-analytics > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

warning karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter > istanbul-api > istanbul-lib-instrument > babel-generator > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

warning protractor > webdriver-manager > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score 0):

Warnings do not matter. You should just wait for Angular team to fix that.
However, `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` shoud be installed with version ~2.1